Getting RunError.JsonParseError while trying to convert key-value pairs into JSON string with sorted keys
I’m trying to write a Python program that takes a number of key-value pairs, sorts them by key, and then converts them into a JSON string. However, I keep getting a RunError.JsonParseError when I try to run the code.
Here is the code I wrote:
import json

n = int(input())
dict_ = {}

for i in range(n):
    key, value = str(input()).split(' ')
    dict_[key] = value

sorted_by_keys = dict(sorted(dict_.items()))
json_object = json.dumps(sorted_by_keys, separators=(',', ':'))

print(json_object)

I am getting a RunError.JsonParseError when I try to run this code.
I’ve tried using separators=(',', ':') to remove extra spaces between keys and values, but it doesn’t seem to solve the problem. The program works for basic dictionary operations but seems to fail when converting it to a JSON string.
Why am I getting the JsonParseError? How can I fix this and ensure the output is a valid JSON string?

Please convert your code sample into a [mre]. input calls are cumbersome and don't let use the same input you're using.

This is not a Python error (RunError.JsonParseError). Most likely, something is wrong with your environment (codePost).

I cannot reproduce this, even if I give some values using your script. @Anerdw is right, you need to give us an actual value of dict_ to use to get your error message, don't make us guess what you typed at your terminal.

note that json.dumps() supports a parameter sort_keys=True
